# Правильно ли составлен текст о Грузии?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография

Наша компания предлогает вам незабываемое путешествие в древнейшую и красивейшую Грузию. В страну солнца, вина и счастья. Чтобы ощутить и одно, и второе, и третее вы должны объязательно приехать к нам и уверяем вас, что отсюда вы уедете полны любовью и радостью что побывали в Грузии. Грузинское гостеприимство, традиционные тосты и вкуснеишые блюда возбудят желания опять вернутся в нашу страну.
Неповторимая красота Грузии, которая пересекается в горах и ровнинах, в морях и реках, в необъятных полупустынях и изумрудных водопадах — навсегда останется в вашей памяти. Обещяем что это будет незабываемое путешествие.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Автор вопроса — не носитель русского языка? Хочу заметить, что «в древнейшую и красивейшую Грузию» звучит как-то непривычно для русскоязычного человека. Кроме того, нельзя, наверное, ощутить вино... Его можно попробовать. И ещё: что пересекается — красота или Грузия? В любом случае звучит как-то некорректно. Я вообще заменила бы многие обороты. Ну, предлагаю так.

Наша компания предлагает вам незабываемое путешествие в древнейшую и красивейшую страну — Грузию. Это страна солнца и счастья. Чтобы ощутить и то, и другое, вы должны  приехать к нам. Уверяем вас, что отсюда вы уедете с радостью от посещения этой страны. Грузинское гостеприимство, вкуснейшие блюда, тосты возбудят желание опять вернуться сюда. Неповторимая красота Грузии: горы и равнины, моря и реки, необъятные полупустыни и изумрудные водопады — всё это навсегда останется в вашей памяти.
Обещаем, что это будет незабываемое путешествие.

Я, конечно, многое перекроила... Но Вы можете редактировать исправленный мною текст согласно своему желанию.

Comment: Мне понравилось!

Comment: Ну, это хорошо). Хотя всё равно несколько несовершенный вариант, по моему мнению. Но если бы я правила дальше, конечный результат был бы очень далёк от оригинального текста, а мне хотелось сохранить ещё и авторские выражения.

Comment: Всегда можно отшлифовывать текст.

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО ! Я оченеь довольно .Cпасибо

Comment: Не за что! Удачи Вам и Вашей компании :-) .

Answer (score 1):

Наша компания предлагает вам незабываемое путешествие в древнейшую и красивейшую Грузию ― в страну солнца, вина и счастья. Приезжайте к нам, чтобы получить удивительные ощущения и наполниться любовью и радостью от пребывания в Грузии! Национальное гостеприимство, традиционные тосты и вкуснейшие блюда поддержат желание побывать в нашей стране еще раз [или: ...желание опять вернуться в нашу страну]. Красота Грузии ― в гармонии гор и равнин, в слиянии морей и рек, в контрасте необъятных полупустынь и изумрудных водопадов. Неповторимая природа навсегда запечатлится в вашей памяти!

"...навсегда останется в вашей памяти" больше подходит для эпитафии.
Последнее предложение (*Обещяем что это будет незабываемое путешествие*) я бы вообще изничтожила: Вы УЖЕ ОБЕЩАЛИ незабываемое путешествие ― в самом начале.
Возможно, что-то из моих поправок Вам подойдет.

Comment: Не соглашусь по поводу оборота "навсегда останется в вашей памяти". Вот один из многочисленных примеров из сфер, далеких от эпитафий. "Это зрелище навсегда останется в вашей памяти и в вашей душе" (Жданова Марина Алексеевна. Кандидат. пед. наук,. доцент кафедры социальной педагогики РГПУ им. Герцена. Книга "Неформальный Петербург")

Comment: _навсегда останется в вашей памяти_  в оригинале "оторван" от текста, поэтому мне так и показалось. А в Вашем примере оборот распространён и воспринимается уже совсем по-другому.

Comment: Согласен с Вами :)

Answer (score 1):

Оригинальный текст требует не только исправления ошибок, но и некоторой стилистической правки. Вот мой вариант:

*Наша компания предлaгает вам незабываемое путешествие в древнейшую и красивейшую  страну Грузию — страну солнца, счастья и вина. Вы обязательно должны приехать к нам, чтобы увидеть Грузию своими глазами, — и уверяем вас, что ваше сердце наполнится радостью и любовью к этой стране. Вас покорят грузинское гостеприимство, традиционные тосты и вкуснейшие блюда нашей кухни. В вашей памяти навсегда останется неповторимая красота грузинской природы, в которой соединились горы и равнины, моря и реки, необъятные полупустыни и изумрудные водопады. Вам обязательно захочется вернуться сюда!*

Примечание.

Обещание незабываемого путешествия в конце пришлось убрать, так как оно уже дано в начале. Но хотелось закончить каким-то восклицанием. Поэтому я поставил в конце обещание, что гостям обязательно захочется вернуться, убрав эти слова  из середины текста (они стояли после описания грузинских угощений, хотя логичнее отнести их ко всему вместе и поставить в конце)

Comment: Да, так, безусловно, лучше!